# Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, navigation-drawer

Esta funcionando corretamente na maioria dos dispositivos, contudo em outros dispositivos esta ocorrendo o seguinte erro:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

Já procurei e encontrei resultados no Stackoverflow em Inglês mas nada adiantou

**XML**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_acompanhar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_acompanhar"
        app:menu="@menu/a_acompanhar_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**app.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.hackaton.up"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.7.3'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.7.3'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.3'
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0"
}
```

**EDIT**

**Styles.xml**:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

**v21/styles.xml**:

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Como está a classe na qual vocês está tentando chamar esse Drawer?

Comment: Qual a versão do Android nos dispositivos que dão o problema ? Na doc do developers eles recomendam tratar corretamente as interações da NavigationView com a StatusBar nas API 21+

Comment: Versões 5.0 para baixo, geralmente 4.4.2

Answer (score 1):

Fala Giancarlo,

Tenta adicionar o item `app:itemTextColor="@color/a_color"` ao seu NavigationView, vai ficar dessa forma:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
   android:id="@+id/nav_view"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_gravity="start"
   android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
   app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_acompanhar"
   app:menu="@menu/a_acompanhar_drawer"
   app:itemTextColor="@color/a_color" />
```

Tive esse problema uma vez e resolvi dessa forma.

Também pode ser algum problema no sey styles.xml, caso essa solução não resolva, posta o seu style.xml aqui pra gente.

Abraços.

Comment: Fiz isso e o erro ainda persiste, não tem o a_color e coloquei outro valor. Vou editar com o styles.xml. O maior problema é que o erro é genérico.